# Page doesn't load as it fetches the current location

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, ui-automation

I am trying to automate below scenario:

1. Go to BestBuy.com
2. Search for laptops
3. Click on specific HP laptop from result page
4. Click on Add to cart
5. Click on View Cart
6. Add postal code and click on Update button and Click on Continue to checkout button
7. Now click on Continue link
8. Enter all details and click on continue
9. Enter wrong credit card details and click on continue
10. Verify Error message

Here on after step #7, it automatically detects my current location and adds it in url(eg. https://www.bestbuy.ca/checkout/?qit=1#/en-ca/shipping/GJ/390020)and page doesn't load which fails my code. I block website to fetch current location (through pop up) but it doesn't help.
Can anybody suggest me how to solve this problem.

Please find below code:

```
package seleniumtestingscript;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class BestBuyScenario {

    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;
    JavascriptExecutor js;
    Select select;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void launch_Browser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G:\\Sheetal\\Selenium_Program_Practice\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String URL = "https://www.bestbuy.com/";
        driver.get(URL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void HappyPath() throws InterruptedException {

    //Click on Canada link
    WebElement Canada_Link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Canada"));
    Canada_Link.click();

    //wait till search page loads
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("search")));

    WebElement search_field = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/input[@aria-label = 'Search Best Buy']"));
    search_field.clear();
    search_field.sendKeys("Laptops");

    //wait till auto complete list is displayed
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul/li/a[starts-with(@class,'autocompleteLink')]")));

    //Click on laptops displayed in autocomplete list
    List<WebElement> autocomplete_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul/li/a[starts-with(@class,'autocompleteLink')]"));
    for(int i = 0; i<autocomplete_list.size(); i++)
    {
        if(autocomplete_list.get(i).getText().contains("laptops"))
        {
            System.out.println(autocomplete_list.get(i).getText());
            autocomplete_list.get(i).click();
            break;

        }
    }
    System.out.println("After loop");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    //wait till laptop page loads and verify the page title
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div/h1[contains(text(),'Laptops & MacBooks')]")));

    System.out.println("After title on laptop page");
    //Scroll page till HP laptop gets visible and click on that laptop link
    js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1500);", "");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'HP 15.6\" Laptop - Silver (Intel Core i3-1005G1')]"))).click();


    //click on Add to cart button
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,150);", "");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Add to Cart')]"))).click();
    System.out.println("Add to cart clicked");
    //WebElement add_to_cart_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Add to Cart')]"));
    //add_to_cart_button.click();


    //Switch to pop up and click on view cart button

    driver.switchTo().activeElement();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@data-automation='view-cart-confirmation']"))).click();
    //WebElement view_cart_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-automation='view-cart-confirmation']"));
    //view_cart_button.click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("postalCode"))).clear();
    WebElement postal_input = driver.findElement(By.id("postalCode"));
    //postal_input.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.chord("a")); //select all text in textbox
    //postal_input.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE); //delete it
    postal_input.sendKeys("M9V1S3"); //enter new text
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-automation='enter-postal-code-button']")).click();

    //click on continue_to_checkout_button
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,350);", "");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//div/div/a[@data-automation='continue-to-checkout'])[position()=2]"))).click();
    //WebElement continue_to_checkout_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div/div/a[@data-automation='continue-to-checkout'])[position()=2]"));
    //continue_to_checkout_button.click();

    //wait till continue button is displayed and then click on it
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@data-automation= 'guest-continue']/a")));
    WebElement continue_link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-automation= 'guest-continue']/a"));
    continue_link.click();



    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("email")));
    WebElement email_field = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
    email_field.sendKeys("sheetal@test.com");
    WebElement firstName_field = driver.findElement(By.id("firstName"));
    firstName_field.sendKeys("Sheetal");
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,150);", "");
    WebElement lastName_field = driver.findElement(By.id("lastName"));
    lastName_field.sendKeys("Patel");
    WebElement addressLine_field = driver.findElement(By.id("addressLine"));
    addressLine_field.sendKeys("Etobicoke");
    WebElement city_field = driver.findElement(By.id("city"));
    city_field.sendKeys("Toronto");
    WebElement regionCode_field = driver.findElement(By.id("regionCode"));
    Select select = new Select(regionCode_field);
    select.selectByVisibleText("Ontario");
    WebElement postalCode_field = driver.findElement(By.id("postalCode"));
    postalCode_field.sendKeys("M5G 2C3");
    WebElement phone_field = driver.findElement(By.id("phone"));
    phone_field.sendKeys("8989564646");
    WebElement continue_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Continue')]"));
    continue_button.click();

    WebElement cardnumber_field = driver.findElement(By.id("shownCardNumber"));
    cardnumber_field.sendKeys(card_number);
    WebElement month = driver.findElement(By.id("expirationMonth"));

    select = new Select(month);
    select.selectByVisibleText("1");

    WebElement year = driver.findElement(By.id("expirationYear"));
    select = new Select(year);
    select.selectByVisibleText(card_year);

    WebElement cvv = driver.findElement(By.id("cvv"));
    cvv.sendKeys(card_cvv);

    WebElement continue_button1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Continue')]"));
    continue_button1.click();

    WebElement error_msg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='error-msg'])[position()=1]"));
    String actual = error_msg.getText();
    String expected = "Invalid credit card number. Please check your credit card number or use another payment method.";
    Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);


    }





}
```

Comment: Holy shite man you have you card number cvv and expiration in plain text!!! Cancel that card immediately!

Comment: Those are wrong details(random numbers).Added for automation purpose.

Comment: Don't worry . I am always careful when it comes to money.

Comment: you could try setting the webdriver's "unexpected alert behavior" to accept. Default is to notify which throws an error before the next action.

Comment: @pcalkins  can you show me how can I do that?

Comment: Can anyone please help me here.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. The actual problem was whenever I run my script that new instance of browser was allowing to take current location even though I blocked to fetch current location for that site(click on lock icon displayed in https://www.bestbuy.com/ url -> Site settings-> Permission -> Block location).

I searched on Google - how to block to geo location pop up and found few solutions and below solution worked:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                prefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings.geolocation", 2);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```